# 4 for loop optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization

I have the following, extremly ugly peace of code:

```
def cell_hist(gradients):
    h, w, d  = gradients.shape
    window_size = 8
    res_h = int(h / window_size)
    res_w = int(w / window_size)
    bins_number = 9
    bin_width = (180 / bins_number)
    bins = [bin_width * x for x in range(bins_number)]
    result = np.zeros((res_h, res_w, bins_number))

    for a in range(res_h):
        for b in range(res_w):
            fragment = gradients[a*window_size:(a+1)*window_size, b*window_size:(b+1)*window_size]
            hist = np.zeros(bins_number)

            for row in fragment:
                for pixel in row:
                    nbin = int((pixel[1] // bin_width) % 9)
                    hist[nbin] += ((pixel[1] - bins[nbin]) / bin_width) * pixel[0]
                    if nbin != bins_number - 1:
                        hist[nbin+1] += ((bins[nbin+1] - pixel[1]) / bin_width) * pixel[0]
                    else:
                        hist[0] += ((180 - pixel[1]) / bin_width) * pixel[0]
            result[a,b] = hist
    return result
```

I am aware that this is terrible, but I cannot think of any optimization here to get rid of 4 for loops. Is there any tricky numpy indexing which might help here? I would be very grateful for your help!

gradients argument is a matrix which looks like this: (w,h,2). So basically image with two channels.

Comment: You should also explain what you are trying to do with that code: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know that you won't like this answer, but to be honest I don't know. I just have code which I need to use, I know that it gives good results, and I know it's terribly slow. This is the part which I am almost sure is the bottleneck. So I was trying to refactor it without going into details, just checking if my output is the same.

Comment: It's not that I (don't) like the answer. You didn't explain what the code is supposed to do. Do you know what it should do / does? The question doesn't seem to be valid.  Maybe a more suitable place to ask it, would be: https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @CristiFati note that CR *requires* the OP to explain what their code does. [codereview.se] is indeed a good place to ask for help with performance and readablity enhancements, but reviewers usually don't like having to first guess what the purpose of the code is.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: thanks for the tips. Personally I didn't visit that site, but I thought it was better than here. @: In the meantime: -1: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve. Add the missing details, and I'll retract it.

Answer (score 1):

There're ways to do it less 'tabbed inside', with itertools and combinations of nested elements.

But there isn't way to do it corectly in mine opinion.

At first, lets think about what you can do, to split this huge code into few functions which will call each other when necessary, and then name any function/part to make it also not only less ugly, but with readability boost :)

For example i'll split it for something into like this:

```py
def cell_hist(gradients):
    h, w, d  = gradients.shape
    window_size = 8
    res_h = int(h / window_size)
    res_w = int(w / window_size)
    bins_number = 9
    bin_width = (180 / bins_number)
    bins = [bin_width * x for x in range(bins_number)]
    result = np.zeros((res_h, res_w, bins_number))

    for a in range(res_h):
        for b in range(res_w):
            result[a,b] = func2(a, b)

    return result

def func2(a, b):
    fragment = gradients[a*window_size:(a+1)*window_size, b*window_size:(b+1)*window_size]
    hist = np.zeros(bins_number)

    for row in fragment:
        for pixel in row:
            nbin = int((pixel[1] // bin_width) % 9)
            hist[nbin] += ((pixel[1] - bins[nbin]) / bin_width) * pixel[0]
            if nbin != bins_number - 1:
                hist[nbin+1] += ((bins[nbin+1] - pixel[1]) / bin_width) * pixel[0]
            else:
                hist[0] += ((180 - pixel[1]) / bin_width) * pixel[0]
    return hist
```

But there are many variables which u must to transfer with it, then most efficient way to keep it simple. Put it inside some class, this give u simple way to remember variables inside `self.` with keeping code clearly what is necessary, what not :)

Linebreaking also will be usefull for readability, check it:
https://doingmathwithpython.github.io/breaking-long-lines-in-python.html